# Como encadenar operaciones en serie con observables usando el operador rxjs concatMap

Tags: rxjs

Estoy intentando realizar una serie de operaciones encadenadas en una base de datos donde el punto de partida es un conjunto de entidades que recorro y por cada una tengo que ejecutar 3 llamadas a un servicio que accede a la base de datos

```
estudiarConcursos() {
of(...this.data.data.filter(d => d.estudiar == 'Sí'))
.pipe(
  concatMap(
    concurso=>this.dataServiceConcursos.ConcursoEstudiar(concurso)
  ),
  concatMap(
    data => this.dataServiceOfertas.postOferta(this.ConvertirConcursoEnOferta(data))
  ),
  concatMap(
    data =>
       this.dataServiceConcursos.asociarOferta({
        concurso: this.concursoTratado,
        oferta: data
      })
  )
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

}

Por cada concurso iterado tengo que hacer 3 cosas

1. Actualizar su campo Estudiar
2. Crear una oferta asociada
3. Actualizar su campo ofertaId con el ID de la oferta recien creada

Y mi problema está en que en el tercer concatMap necesito acceder al concurso que se está iterando pero en data yo recibo el resultado del concatMap previo, es decir, la oferta recien creada y no se como acceder al valor del concurso con el que comienza todo

Alguna idea, por favor?

Un Saludo

Comment: 3 cosas 1. ¿Has intentado algo? 2. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta e incluir todo lo que sea necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario desde cero sin ir a ciegas y/o entrar en modo entrevista? 3. Aquí hay una serie de recomendaciones que considero útiles para la mejora de preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: 1) Llevo una semana intentando cosas y esto es lo mas lejos que he llegado 2)Estamos hablando de un proyecto de Angular (FrontEnd) y otro de ASP.NET Core con EFCore (BackEnd) que no creo que nadie vaya a reproducir desde cero 3) Todo en esta vida es mejorable gracias por tu ayuda. Creo que el esfuerzo de síntesis que he hecho es suficiente para que cualquiera entienda cual es el problema que no es otro que poder acceder en el tercer conCatMap al valor inicial que se está iterando.

Comment: `1) Llevo una semana intentando cosas y esto es lo mas lejos que he llegad` Inclúyelas por favor, en todos los años que llevo por SOes, las preguntas que tienen intentos de resolución tienen una chance mayor de obtener mejores respuestas. `2)Estamos hablando de un proyecto de Angular (FrontEnd) y otro de ASP.NET Core con EFCore (BackEnd) que no creo que nadie vaya a reproducir desde cero`, me sorprende que en poco más de 5 años que llevas en el sitio, no quede del todo claro la idea de: "código mínimo verificable" que se solicita en las preguntas.

Comment: `Creo que el esfuerzo de síntesis que he hecho es suficiente para que cualquiera entienda cual es el problema que no es otro que poder acceder en el tercer conCatMap al valor inicial que se está iterando`, Aquí te jugó mal la estrategia de síntesis, cuando se realizan preguntas de programación para atender un problema, se necesitan todos los detalles posibles, caso contrario estaríamos jugando al entrevistador y/o caminando a ciegas. Considera incluir el error que aparece en la consola y/o debugger del Angular en caso tengas uno. Saludos.